# Google Apps : SPLIT_BUNDLE 99: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device on Google Console

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I hope you are fine.
So we just uploaded our Apps and we get rejected with this message

**SPLIT_BUNDLE 99: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device**

I have no clue at all of which part of the Data security form I should change.
Does someone have a clue of this Split_Bundle 99 ?

And yes I tried to google it without result.

There is a screenshot of the full message
[ScreeshotsEmailGoogle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN9nE.jpg)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic